# navigation drawer white space above the items

Tags: android, xml

i am using the include to inflate the other layouts into the Home screen and i also want to use the scroll view in it but when use it its not displaying the view in the home screen please help me out here

[this is navigation drawer picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLF00.png)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/hmebar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <include layout="@layout/banner" />

            <include layout="@layout/featured_products" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Did you put your xml code in Drawable layout namespace?

Comment: i am getting my navigation drawer items dynamically from JSON

Comment: i had updated my post please once see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the code not in xml u had calling data from the same arraylist give different arraylist each of it